# How do I put "%20" as a string in curl data?

Tags: bash, curl, urlencode

I am trying to put `"%20"` in the bash date format without it being interpreted. I am using the date string as a parameter in a `curl` request.
This was my approach in making a call to an api whose parameter includes a date string formatted with a space `(YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS)`.
The api's doc gives an example as `"date=2014-04-30%2002:18:36"`.
But the company's web version of the api shows `"date=2014-04-30+02%3A18%3A36"`.

I've tried `date=$(date +%Y-%m-%d%%20%H:%M:%S)` in my shell script, which does produce `2016-12-19%2016:03:26`, but is still not working correctly.
I've also tried `curl --data-urlencode` without any success.

Are my approaches just totally wrong?

**Update for additional information:** I've tried `date=$(date +%Y-%m-%d+%H%%3A%M%%3A%S)`, which gives me `2016-12-19+16%3A17%3A41`. But the returned data is still inaccurate.
The version on the website accepts `"2016-12-12 00:00:00"` and I am able to get accurate data.

Comment: Have you tried using the other version: `+` instead of `%20` in your request?

Comment: @sebastianForsberg I've tried date=$(date +%Y-%m-%d+%H%%3A%M%%3A%S), which gives me 2016-12-19+16%3A17%3A41. But the returned data is still inaccurate. The version on the website accepts "2016-12-12 00:00:00" and I am able to get accurate data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One version to get it into a shell variable and then to curl:

```
#!/bin/bash
output=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" | sed 's/ /%20/g')
curl -d date=$output http://example.com
```

One way to let curl do the URL encoding itself:

```
curl --data-urlencode date=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") http://example.com
```